# Can ping, but not connect to endpoint hosted on another machine from the same network

Tags: linux, windows, flask, networking, localhost

I'm currently attempting to run a web api endpoint from a Flask project from my Manjaro Linux machine on a Windows machine.

The api and the endpoint works fine on the localhost (running on the port 5000) from the machine that is running it, which has an IP address 192.168.1.12.

However, when I open the endpoint's URL address from the browser using the address 192.168.1.12:5000, it displays a connection refused message.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out; you need to configure Flask to make the app run from external machines within the network, using

```
flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```